# Min-width and Max-width for an webpage using Screen properties

Tags: css

I have a situation here, i need to design a website and i am stuck on the question of working my webpage in some particular resolution.

I have used %age approach in my web page content and need to find a min-width/max-width on which i can have the whole web page or body to be restricted if it was a specific monitor to be looked on.

Our end-users are on following specs:
HP L1955
aspect ratio : 4:3
resolution : 1280*1024

Are there any calculations with above data to know the best fit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just want to design it for best in specific resolution as mentioned and want to see quite viewable items on other resolutions or widescreens stuf...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the styling of the web page based on a specific resolution of screen, you can use `@media` queries. Check this stackoverflow question out: [What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

For example, if you wanted to specify some CSS code for a screen of 1024 or less, you could do this in your CSS file:

`@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
{
/* code here */
}`

Comment: OK thats a point i would keep in mind; but will this work on IE 8 or lower?

Comment: @GOK It looks like that if you **need** to support IE6-8, you won't be able to use traditional `@media` queries, but could use a little JScript: http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/04/how-to-have-your-media-queries-and-eat-ie-too/