# Make horizontal bar hidden at mobile website

Tags: mobile, web

I really need someone to help me on this.

The slide out menu cause the horizontal scrollbar appear in mobile website, it's hidden in desktop version.

Somebody please help me get rid of that annoying scrollbar. Thanks.

For your reference, here is the website: http://siuyian.com/test4

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question completely. I hope @media queries will help you out to make your website responsive.
Please refer to the following link to understand it further:
[What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

Comment: definitely not causing by any css elements, the slide out menu have negative value, once it slide out, the horizontal bar just appear.

Comment: the overflow:hidden works great on desktop, but not mobile browser

Comment: I tried the link you posted in my mobile browser as well, and did not get the horizontal scroll bar. can you post a little more explanation of your problem?

Comment: I try it on anroid and iphone, both of it show horizontal scrollbar, did you try to slide the menu first? slide the menu, and sroll vertically, then you will see it

Comment: ooh, i lock the horizontal scrollbar, so you can't scroll horizontally

Comment: Oh now I got your point. Have a look at this http://getbootstrap.com/  in your mobile browser

Comment: you are trying to slide the menu horizontally. Try sliding it vertically along with the page.

Comment: i don't want to slide it vertically, is that any other solution on my problem?

Comment: i have no problem with vertical menu

Comment: Then you`ll have to use the @media queries I mentioned earlier and try hiding your main page content when you slide the menu. That is the only solution I can see as of now.