# float left, max-width and flow control

Tags: html, css

Ideally I want a variable width left panel between 16-30em and a right panel fixed at 16em wide. When the screen shrinks to 32em or less, I want the right panel to flow underneath the left. and I want this all left aligned.

I have found several examples of the side by side, but only a fixed width on the left by floating it and variable right panel, or floating right and a variable left panel. I managed to put an outer holding div round things and made the layout work right to the point I want to flow the right panel under the left (or the left under the right - I'm not fussed which):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ph3S8/2/

I've tried using the `@media (min-width: 15em)` and nesting some changes in there because basically when the screen is less that `.left:min-width + .right:min-width` I just need to take out the float:right on the right panel, but nothing seems to take effect (I'm not sure if it is supposed to in jsfiddle, but it doesn't on my real example either. I don't mind which panel pops under the other but I just need it work for mobile devices with standard CSS -  I have other stuff that works when the screen gets to 72ems etc, but I didn't write that :)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: did it solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, based on my original post without a margin it did. When I added the margin in I had to remember to take it out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this media query.

```
@media (max-width: 15em)
{
    .right {
         width: auto;
         float:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`This Question Asked in Stackoverflow on:
[What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

Review this page:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Media Screens For All Browsers And Events

```
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexanderi, This is a great reference, and I did read this. CSS is still a little bit of a dark art for me and while I can colour, pad and font with the best of them, reading that I had more questions than answers for my little issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Allan's answer I updated my fiddle to try and work out what I was doing wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/Ph3S8/3/

I have to move the margin **and** the float into the media selector as here:

```
@media (min-width:17em) {
    .right {
        float:right;
    }
    .left {
        margin-right:5em;
    }
}
```

For some reason I had to add 2 em's of padding on the selector or the div's overlapped.

Anyhow I'm posting this as a clarification to my original post, Allan's answer is better than mine.