# Mobile devices of the page is greater

Tags: jquery, html, css, viewport, mobile-devices

I have a problem with one page on mobile devices

It is a fact that some of the subpages of this site are partly enlarged.

It is interesting that the part of the page is enlarged in the source code.

[image: Screenshot]

Unfortunately it does only some pages.

web is to: [www.kitelementshop.com](http://www.kitelementshop.com)

A page that displays poorly on mobiles as:
[link1](http://www.kitelementshop.com/home/about-us.html)
[link2](http://www.kitelementshop.com/home/terms-and-conditions.html)

Very interesting is that the two products are displayed differently and are on the same template.
[bad show](http://www.kitelementshop.com/produkt/resolve2103-bag.html)
[good show](http://www.kitelementshop.com/produkt/twin-tip-kiteboard-revert.html)

**finally resolved by switching the viewport, but only masked the problem unsolved**

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I think the page is not made responsive and for mobile devices you have to change the font-size so as to make it clear. Use responsive css to tackle small screen size. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css

Comment: It're true, but it does not solve the problem

Comment: can you provide the link where the text is partly enlarged

Comment: in the text are links link1 and link2

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

With that the phone knows which scale it needs to start with and computes the font-sizes accordingly.

If you try inspecting it without the viewport meta tag you can see that the font is computed to 39px! With the viewport tag its calculated to 12px - the value that you have put in your CSS.

Comment: I tried that too, but first it does not work gallery and page loads always approximations.
Another thing is that now I have added <p>Testovací p</p> tag to the header, body and footer, and only in the footer is displayed correctly.

Comment: Well the viewport tag doesn't fix all the other issues - thats right, but it fixes the font issue - which was the question.

You have put a lot of fixed width's in your page f.ex. 1000 px on a lot of elements - 1000px's remains 1000px whether or not its a desktop or a mobile device - hence the phone needs to scroll. 

What you need to do it completely rewrite most of your CSS im affraid - or rather just forget about supporting a mobile device. Sorry but its not that simple.