# Changing the page style on resize

Tags: css

Can you help me to understand the idea of changing the page style on resize it,as if we
use another style that suits with the size of the window and make you see all page content.
I see that in some website 
[like this page](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index4.html)
I check it's css and script ,I think the idea is in css ,but I don't sure and I wana know 
if there are any jquery effectiveness or what css properties effectiveness to do that.
Thanks for help

Comment: Keyword: CSS Media Queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS media screen. To do that just view these links:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

[What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

And also you can use [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Answer (score 1):

You need so-called [responsive theme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (i.e., a theme that looks great on desktops, tablet devices, and mobile devices). Most of Bootstrap themes are responsive. See at [Start Bootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/).