# if screen is lower than 800 run this CSS, else run this CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering if I somehow can create a if statement that if the screen is lower than 800 it runs **mobile.css** else runs another CSS file.

My idea is to create something like this:

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
  run.this.css = "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" />";
}
else {
  run.this.css = "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" />";
}
```

Comment: you can simply use media queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use 1 CSS file and use media queries to override:

```
/* DESKTOP.CSS CODE HERE */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    /* MOBILE.CSS CODE HERE */
}
```

If you really want them in seperate CSS files you can do the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use media queries, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css"
    media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css"
    media="screen and (min-width: 801px)" />
```

What you are trying to achieve is called `responsive design`.
A complete tutorial of it is here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/
Media queries tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the media queries in css. for e.g:

```
/* Media queries in css */
@media(max-width: 800px) {
    // for 800px screen
}
@media(min-width: 801px) {
    // for larger then 800px screen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its advisable to use `media query` for responsive

```
/* MEDIA QUERY FOR MOBILE DEVICES **********/    
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

But, if you are concern with performance issue and you want to load responsive code css only for mobile than you can use javascript for that.

```
<!-- mobile.css will load only if the resolution is less than 768 -->
if(screen.width<768)
{
    file = location.pathname.split( "/" ).pop();
    link = document.createElement( "link" );
    link.href = "mobile.css";
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.media = "screen,print";
    document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( link );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { }
```

Something like this can help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot use mediaqueries as everyone mention (for example if you need to support IE8), you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width < 480) {
            $("body").removeClass("c800 c600");
            $("body").addClass("c400");

        } else if ((width >= 481) && (width < 600)) {
            $("body").removeClass("c400 c800");
            $("body").addClass("c600");

        } else if ((width >= 601) && (width < 800)) {
            $("body").removeClass("c400 c600");
            $("body").addClass("c800");

        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("c800 c400 c600");

        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
});
```

Instead of load different stylesheets, this code add a class in the `body` tag, and then you can create 'fake' mediaqueries:

```
.container {width:900px}
.c800 .container {width:700px;}
.c600 .container {width:500px;}
```

Comment: That's a poor solution. For media queries in IE8, just use a polyfill, for example: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: In my case, we need this solution because the polyfill doesn't work with Zope Plone. By the way, there could be several reasons because you can't use the polyfill (client requirements, for example). I wish I had this response a year ago, because sometimes you can't use the perfect solution...

Comment: I'm sorry, but it sounds like you didn't try hard enough to make a polyfill work. Sure, this works but there's no way this should be going on a new site.