# Automatically Resize a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I make my browser window small, the text starting with "Open" ends up taking up several lines and I can't get the everything below to be pushed down lower.  Instead, the buttons and hidden, and the main image is blocked by the text.  How can I get the resizing to happen automatically?  The site is: http://opensimulationsystems.org/

I tried adding "height:auto" to the navbar-header in Chrome developer tools, but "auto" isn't an option.  I'm using Bootstrap Theme template.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=".">Open Simulation Systems: The Common Agent-Based Simulation Framework (CABSF) & The Agent and Simulation Repository</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS?

Comment: I'm not positive but lately I've been learning about the size property called rem, my curousity is of that which does it resize when resizing the window if not you could use media queries for this .

Comment: Suggestion: If you intend for people to be able to view the site on small screens, maybe you should make the site title shorter or use a smaller font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because `navbar-brand` class is floating.

[image]

One way of fixing that is using a [media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css) for small screens on your css, setting `navbar-brand` to not float. Something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the `float:left` that is making it overlap. For smaller screen sizes you can apply specific styles  with [media](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries) queries like

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
        .navbar-brand {
          float: none;
          height:auto;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will remove `float:left` element style from `.navbar-brand` then you have to set your header again with padding and all the other things.

But if you remove `height:50px` from .navbar-brand then it will automatically set all the things. And in media query you can adjust with the width of `.navbar-brand.`