# Media Queries work when I re size the window but don't work when on other devices

Tags: html, css, media

Ive been looking all over and I cant find any solution to this. My media queries don't work on mobile devices but they work when I re size my screen.

YES I do have:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In the head of my document.

Here are what my media queries look like:

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .r-menu {
      display:inline;
    }
    .m-menu {
      display:none;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .res-full {
      width: 100%; 
    }
  }
```

Thanks.

Here is the whole code: http://scratchpad.io/marvelous-holiday-5460

Answer (score 0):

Replace **only screen** with **all**

```
@media all and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .r-menu {
    display:inline;
  }
  .m-menu {
    display:none;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .res-full {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

**screen** is used for computer screens whereas **all** is used for all media type devices

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I have tried a lot this is really annoying, media queries usually work well for me.

Comment: If you update your question with the html it might help us figure out the issue

Comment: It should be noted that not only desktops, but also newer mobile devices identify themselves as the `screen` type. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4189911/2234742

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use "only"?
I found that the only keyword was intended to prevent non-media-query supporting browsers to not load the stylesheet or use the styles. Why don't you try removing it?

Comment: I tried using all instead of only screen and it still doesn't work as you can see from the post below.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the mistake** Use `min-width` not `max-width`

```
/*If screen is less than 900px don't show full menu*/
@media(max-width: 900px) {
    .r-menu {
      display:inline;
    }
    .m-menu {
      display:none;
    }
  }
  /*If screen is greater than 900px then show full menu*/
  @media(min-width: 901px) {
    .res-full {
      width: 100%; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: This did not work either, im going to update my question with all the html

Comment: You have to use min-width because after 900px you want your nav to appear in full form , you were just doing opposite

Comment: min-width screws it up and doesnt work still. and the nav part of the media query does actually work on mobile, its the other parts that dont work

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) { .r-menu {
  display:inline;
}
.m-menu {
  display:none;
}}
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.res-full {
   width: 100%; 
 }}
```

**working all devices & screens**