# Prevent header background image loading in mobile browser using <picture> element

Tags: html, css, image

Is there a way of using the `<picture>` element to stop a page downloading an image when using mobile phone?

I have a site which displays a header image.  Due to the site functionality, it is not possible to use CSS (background image + media query) to prevent the header image being loaded on mobile.  As such I need to use a solution which makes use of either `<img>` or `<picture>` elements.

I was thinking that perhaps I could use the `<picture>` element to load a small, clear image (e.g. 1 pixel image) on mobile and then full background image on larger screens.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="./images/clear-1pixel.png">
  <source srcset="./images/banner.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
  <img src="./images/banner.jpg" alt="Header background">
</picture>
```

Would this be the best approach?  I tried testing it, but it seems that the mobile browser is still loading both images.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to implement the image with CSS.
Make a generic div in the images place then use code such as the one located here:
[What does @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the original post, CSS and media queries are not an option.