# window resizing - sites resize lower than others

Tags: html, css, browser

i need help understanding why in chrome, some websites allow me to resize lower than 475px and other sites in chrome will not let me go below 475px or 487px.

is this a setting in chrome?

i've made a blank file with no css on my server and it does the same thing so i'm thinking its not a css setting.

for example.  I can resize stackoverflow.com down to 390px but i can only resize godaddy.com to 487px.

if there is a setting for this where can i find it or how can i alter it with css?  ive tried setting the min-width on the body element with no success.

Comment: probably this happens because of the @media screen rule applied to the web page. See the following topic for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189868/what-does-media-screen-and-max-width-1024px-mean-in-css

Comment: but if i have a blank page with no styles then media queries wouldn't come into play to restrict my browser being able to go past that.  wouldn't that just adjust my styles for that window size?